# Add a column counts the number of rows where the sum is zero €

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

My basic request sends me back:

```
  SELECT T2.POHNUM 'PO Number',T2.UNID 'Number Of Reception',T1.TOTAMTATIL 'TTC receipt in €'
  FROM F_PRECEIPT T1
     LEFT JOIN F_PRECEIPTD T2 ON T1.UNID = T2.UNIDPReceipt
     LEFT JOIN F_PRECEIPTA T3 ON T2.UNID = T3.UNIDPReceiptd
  where T2.POHNUM = 'CDF150700002'
```

The result is:

| PO Number | Number Of Reception | TTC receipt in € |
| --- | --- | --- |
| CDF150700002 | 73020 | 20364.00 |
| CDF150700002 | 71492 | 20364.00 |
| CDF150700002 | 69897 | 20364.00 |
| CDF150700002 | 67197 | 0.00 |
| CDF150700002 | 73951 | 0.00 |
| CDF150700002 | 68896 | 0.00 |

I would like to:

- count the number of rows in the "Number Of Reception" column by "PO Number"
- Sum up the column "TT receipt in €" by PO Number
- Add a column that counts the number of rows or the "TTC receipt in €" = 0 by PO Number

The expected outcome is as follows:

| PO Number | Number Of Reception | TTC receipt in € | Number of Reception at 0€ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CDF150700002 | 6 | 61092.00 | 3 |

I can't get it all into one line. I automatically have 2 lines because my GROUP BY is on the POHNUM and TOTAMTATIL values.

Result for my actual query:

```
  SELECT T2.POHNUM 'PO Number'
    ,COUNT(T1.UNID) 'Number Of Reception'
    ,SUM(T1.TOTAMTATIL) 'TTC receipt in €'
    ,CASE
        WHEN T1.TOTAMTATIL = 0 THEN COUNT(T1.UNID)
    END 'Number of Reception at 0€'
  FROM F_PRECEIPT T1
  LEFT JOIN F_PRECEIPTD T2 ON T1.UNID = T2.UNIDPReceipt
  LEFT JOIN F_PRECEIPTA T3 ON T2.UNID = T3.UNIDPReceiptd
  where T2.POHNUM = 'CDF150700002'
  GROUP BY T2.POHNUM, T1.TOTAMTATIL
```

| PO Number | Number Of Reception | TTC receipt in € | Number of Reception at 0€ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CDF150700002 | 3 | 0.00 | 3 |
| CDF150700002 | 3 | 61092.00 | NULL |

Answer (score 1):

You could use the second query as a subquery and then SUM the values together, illustrated in this *untested* code:

```
SELECT  [PO Number],
        SUM([Number Of Reception]) AS [Number Of Reception],
        SUM([TTC receipt in €]) AS [TTC receipt in €],
        SUM(ISNULL([Number of Reception at 0€], 0)) AS [Number of Reception at 0€]
  FROM  (
        SELECT T2.POHNUM 'PO Number'
          ,COUNT(T1.UNID) 'Number Of Reception'
          ,SUM(T1.TOTAMTATIL) 'TTC receipt in €'
          ,CASE
              WHEN T1.TOTAMTATIL = 0 THEN COUNT(T1.UNID)
          END 'Number of Reception at 0€'
        FROM F_PRECEIPT T1
        LEFT JOIN F_PRECEIPTD T2 ON T1.UNID = T2.UNIDPReceipt
        LEFT JOIN F_PRECEIPTA T3 ON T2.UNID = T3.UNIDPReceiptd
        where T2.POHNUM = 'CDF150700002'
        GROUP BY T2.POHNUM, T1.TOTAMTATIL
        ) a
  GROUP BY [PO Number]
```

This uses the output of your second query and then simply `SUM`s together all of the columns grouped by `PO Number`.  The `ISNULL` is there on the `Number of Reception at 0€` column to catch the rows that have `NULL` values.

Comment: Thank you also for your answer but the first answer seems simpler to me.

Answer (score 1):

You need a different `SUM()` and a different `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT 
   T2.POHNUM 'PO Number',
   COUNT(T1.UNID) 'Number Of Reception',
   SUM(T1.TOTAMTATIL) 'TTC receipt in €',
   SUM(CASE WHEN T1.TOTAMTATIL = 0 THEN 1 END) 'Number of Reception at 0€'
FROM F_PRECEIPT T1
LEFT JOIN F_PRECEIPTD T2 ON T1.UNID = T2.UNIDPReceipt
LEFT JOIN F_PRECEIPTA T3 ON T2.UNID = T3.UNIDPReceiptd
WHERE T2.POHNUM = 'CDF150700002'
GROUP BY T2.POHNUM
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted! Thank you very much for your help